# Flag a product to be updated in next scheduled run. Change index status manually

Tags: magento-1.9, indexer

We have some scripts which updates few product attributes directly, I want to set the product to be picked up in the next schedular cron and push it in to solr. Currently the only possible way seems to be to issue a save() on product which is costly. Is there any other way of changing the index status of a product?